# Trending Web Technologies

Tags: mean-stack

As the two terms MEAN stack and full stack web development are trending, a person like me with enough time(almost a year) before graduating, is put into a dilemma of choosing which side to learn before getting into some actual deal of work. I am currently learning CakePHP but have a gut feeling that Sailsjs might be equally trending after 5 years from now. The reason I begin with "the php side" or full stack if you wish to describe it as that, is that somewhere, it feels that MEAN stack is still not as familiar to the people who get their job done via freelancers(I want to become one too aiming toptal maybe after 10 years from now ;) and focusing on it more might be like being simply optimistic.

Now I would like to know that is it a good idea to work with structured and semi-structured data also along with unstructured data using nosql databases...?

Comment: Whatever concrete API you learn today will be obsolete in 6 months. Learning to learn (ie, cerebral plasticity) is far more important than particular platforms.

Comment: Thats what I use to be told when I just began as a student of engineering in cs...Kinda feelin it nowadays..

Answer (score 1):

I am about to graduate this semester. I have done a lot of web development but my experience is that those web dev skills are no longer very valued in the industry. You can see that those knowledge are easily accessible, anyone with very fundamental background knowledge can pick them up really quickly, and everyone has many of those projects on their resume. I just feel that recruiters do not seem to care about those projects anymore.

My opinion is, if you are a cs major, spend time digging into operating system, communication networks, AI, statistics/data mining, open sourced projects, etc. Stop wasting time in what a high school graduate can do.

Comment: I have a different perspective on things...Thanks for the piece of advise though..

Comment: All of my idea was to do some webapps which also reflect my engineering skills which might include some sophisticated  apps...Anyways I am working to improve my datastructures and trying to do a little more cuda along with regular syllabus